# List last N docker images

Tags: docker

I have 50+ docker images existing locally. It's tough to manage them.
Hence, I only want to list last 5 images created i.e. modify the
`docker images` command to be able to filter only latest 5 created images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this command:

```
docker images | tail -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use this command:

`docker images --format '{{.ID}} | {{.Repository}} | {{.Tag}} | {{.CreatedSince}} | {{.CreatedAt}} | {{.Size}}' | tail -5`

```
.ID            -- ImageID
.Repository    -- Image repository
.CreatedSince  -- Lapsed time since the image was created
.Size          -- Image Size
.CreatedAt     -- Time when the image was created
```